Columns Blowing Out Of Parent Row
I use a custom responsive grid on my website as a way to learn independently, understand how exactly they work and reduce bloat.
My custom grid suddenly starting blowing out and I can't figure out why.
Pretty standard responsive grid. Works like so: Container > Row > Columns.
What I want:
4 columns across. I've put together a quick illo to demenstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

What is happening:
DEMO: https://stg-nightshiftstudio-staging.kinsta.cloud/sample-page-do-not-delete/
(They are wrapping)


/*-- PARENT--*/
.grid__container{
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 96%;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid__row{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  height: 100%;
}

/*-- WHEN THERE IS MARGIN REMOVE IT FROM EDGES OF OUTER ROW TO--*/ AFFORD SPACE
.grid__row.grid__margin-x {
    margin-left: -0.9375rem;
    margin-right: -0.9375rem;

/*-- 4 COLUMNS - GUTTER SO THEY ALL FIT--*/
.grid__row.grid__margin-x > .grid__cell.grid__cell__medium--4{
   width: calc(25% - 1.875rem);
}

/*--- GUTTER ADDED TO COLUMN----*/
.grid__row.grid__margin-x > .grid__cell {
   margin-left: 0.9375rem;
   margin-right: 0.9375rem;
}
 <div class="grid__container">
      <div class="grid__row grid__margin-x">
        <div class="grid__cell grid__cell__medium--4">
          <h1 class="text-center">THIS IS A HEADING: 1<h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__cell grid__cell__medium--4">
          <h1 class="text-center">THIS IS A HEADING: 1<h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__cell grid__cell__medium--4">
          <h1 class="text-center">THIS IS A HEADING: 1<h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__cell grid__cell__medium--4">
          <h1 class="text-center">THIS IS A HEADING: 1<h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




Margin is being added to each cell to provide the gutter (0.9375rem)
The margin on the outer row is being subtracted to afford space for the gutter (1.875rem)
I was expecting this to allow all 4-columns to appear in a row, based off of many responsive frameworks.

What is going on?

Why are you not simply using a CSS grid here? No need for structural markup, much simpler column definitions without all the calculation stuff etc.

remove the row and cell divs, and put display: grid; grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr)); gap: 1.875rem; on your grid-container, and you're done.

@connexo Because this is an entire framework not just an isolated component. Not going to rewrite the entire thing.

That sounds like a painful technical debt.

If I understand correctly, you want the grid to show 4 columns next to each other. Just change 33% to 25% and you are done.
.grid__row.grid__margin-x > .grid__cell.grid__cell__medium--4{
   width: calc(25% - 1.875rem);
}


omg lol. That was the issue. My variables were backwards for 4 columns and 3. Really just needed a fresh set of eyes. Wooooow-- thank you so much haha!

Anytime! Do you mind accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark?

I corrected my framework so that 4-columns is 25%, but the issue persists, unfortunately. I was mistaken. It fixes itself when I put justify-content: center on grid__row but then that centers text throughout my website.
